# While loop not working functioning properly, infinite loop?

Tags: java, while-loop

I have a program that will allow a user to select 1 of 4 choices, then have the program execute that choice and revert back to the menu of 4 choices. For some reason, it infinitely loops the choice they choose. If I enter 1, it keeps asking for the percentage and doesn't go back to the menu, and I really don't know how I can fix this. I've looked at a few infinite loop posts but still having problems. Here is the code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExerciseThree
{
public static void main ( String[] argsv )
{

    float percent = 0;
    double grade = 0;
    double totalAvg = 0;
    double total = 0;
    double gradeAvg = 0;

    int gradeCounter = 0;
    int quit;
    int choice = 0;



    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println( "Please choose one of the following: \n 1 - Set percentage of total for new grades \n 2 - Enter new grades \n 3 - Get average \n 4 - Quit ");



    while (choice != 4) {

                    choice = input.nextInt();

        switch (choice)
        {

            case 1:         
                System.out.println( "Enter a percentage to multiply by" );
                percent = input.nextFloat(); 


            break;



            case 2:
                System.out.println( "Enter grades" );
                grade = input.nextDouble();
                total = total + grade;
                gradeCounter = gradeCounter + 1;
                gradeAvg = (double) total / gradeCounter;
            break;      



            case 3:
                System.out.println( "You have chosen to get the average" );
                totalAvg = totalAvg + percent * grade;
                totalAvg = input.nextDouble();          
            break;



            default: 
                System.out.println( "You have chosen to quit" );
                quit = input.nextInt();
            break; 


        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You didn't update `choice` inside the loop.

Comment: It is good style to leave a space after `if`, `while`, `for` and `switch`, but not inside the brackets (e.g. do `if (flag)` but not `if ( flag )`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should assign to `choice` inside the loop, not outside it. Your current code sets it once and never changes it again.

Comment: Alright, I moved it inside the loop (I edited the code) but I'm still getting the same issue :/

Comment: Now it isn't looping, but when I enter a number, and press enter it just puts a new space below the number that I've entered. It isn't saving the input and bringing the user back to the 4 choice menu.

Comment: @user3304333: You are still printing the menu outside the loop.

Comment: I have everything working smoothly, but I would like to know how I can enter more than 1 grade in Case 2 without going back to the main menu or having the user have to input a number to exit the loop. I want them to be able to enter how ever many numbers they would like, then press enter to average all of those grades.

Answer (score 0):

This --> choice = input.nextInt();
Should be inside of --> while ( choice != 4 ) at the very end.